# Check if string contains leading letters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How can I check if my string contains leading letters? In C# is easy, but I am doing this in SQL. Is there a way to check this? If so, how can I remove it?

EX:
@MyString = 'A1234'

Updated string = '1234'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
   SET your_column = SUBSTRING(your_column, 2, DATALENGTH(your_column))
 WHERE your_column LIKE '[A-Za-z]%'
```

Comment: I think you should change `DATALENGTH()` to `LEN()`: if the type is UNICODE (and `NVARCHAR` is used extensively nowadays) `DATALENGTH()` will 'double up' the length.

Answer (score 1):

For one leading letter, you can do:

```
IF NOT ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@MyString, 1, 1))
    SET @MyString = SUBSTRING(@MyString, 2, LEN(@MyString))
```

You can repeat that until there are no more letters.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping SUBSTRING in an IF...if you want to check

```
substring(@MyString,1,1) = 'A'
```

or just

```
declare @val varchar(10)

set @val = substring(@MyString,1,1)
```